# Terminal - clear half screen

Tags: terminal, iterm2

I know that using cmd + K can clear the entire screen buffer. 
I am wondering is there a way to just clear half of the screen buffer?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>cmd+K</kbd> maps to the menu item for clearing the visible screen (the screen buffer).  That does not include the scrollback (it is a similar question, but different).

iTerm2's preferences and menu do not show any *direct* way to clear half of the screen.

However, iTerm2 emulates (like Terminal.app) most of the VT100 control sequences.  You could add a binding in your shell which (given a suitable key of your choice) tells the shell to echo a control sequence which clears from the current cursor position (a) until the beginning of the screen or (b) to the end of the screen.  Since it honors the save/restore cursor controls, you could even make it clear exactly half of the screen if you know the size, e.g.,

- save the cursor position
- jump to the middle of the screen
- clear (which half?) half of the screen
- restore the cursor position

Since it would use your shell, I called that *indirect*.

As noted, Terminal.app implements *most* of the VT100 control sequences.  In ncurses, the appropriate `TERM` would be [`nsterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-nsterm) which is known to provide the VT100-style save/restore cursor.  You can use [`tput`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) to extract the corresponding strings for `sc`, `rc` and `cup` from the terminal database.  However (if you wanted to erase to the *beginning* of the screen), you would provide your own string, since that particular flavor is not part of termcap/terminfo.

You can find the relevant VT100 control sequences documented in *[XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)*:

```
ESC 7     Save Cursor (DECSC).
ESC 8     Restore Cursor (DECRC).

CSI Ps ; Ps H
          Cursor Position [row;column] (default = [1,1]) (CUP).

CSI Ps J  Erase in Display (ED).
            Ps = 0  -> Erase Below (default).
            Ps = 1  -> Erase Above.
            Ps = 2  -> Erase All.
            Ps = 3  -> Erase Saved Lines (xterm).
```

Answer (score 0):

Refering [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1579391/673470)

```
# Get ceiling eg: 7/2 = 4
ceiling_divide() {
  ceiling_result=$((($1+$2-1)/$2))
}

clear_rows() {
  POS=$1
  # Insert Empty Rows to push & preserve the content of screen
  for i in {1..$((LINES-POS-1))}; echo
  # Move to POS, after clearing content from POS to end of screen
  tput cup $((POS-1)) 0
}

# Clear quarter
alias ptop='ceiling_divide $LINES 4; clear_rows $ceiling_result'
# Clear half
alias pmid='ceiling_divide $LINES 2; clear_rows $ceiling_result'
# Clear 3/4th
alias pdown='ceiling_divide $((3*LINES)) 4; clear_rows $ceiling_result'
```